# Find Version of JDK installed in Oracle server

Tags: java, oracle11g

My application uses Oracle 11, when i try to load some java file or jar file into the server in JDK 1.6/JRE1.6

versionmajorminor 50.0 error is displayed.

Same files if i load in JDK/JRE 1.4 they are getting loaded.
Please can anyone help me how to find which version of JDK or JRE Oracle server is mapped..?

Comment: Is there any command or query to check which JRE/JDK is installed in oracle 11.2.0..? please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Comment: Cunning in its simplicity!

Comment: @BrianAgnew  I like simple.  It suits me.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The class numbers changed per major release of Java thus:

```
Java 6: Version 50.0
Java 5 (1.5): Version 49.0
Java 1.4.2: Version 48.0
```

Oracle 11 [contains Java 5.](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10233364)

Comment: Is there any command or query to check which JRE/JDK is installed in oracle 11.2.0..?

Answer (score 0):

Below is from [Java Developers’ Perspective on Oracle Database 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/appdev-java-developers-perspective--132536.pdf) under "Portability: Java Standards Support" section

```
The Oracle database 11g JDBC comes in two flavors: ojdbc5.jar for Java 5 (i.e., JDK 1.5) and 
ojdbc6.jar for Java 6 (i.e., JDK 1.6). The ojdbc6.jar supports the new JDBC 4.0 specification
```

Comment: I think that's not relevant since it refers to the JDBC drivers, not the version of Java installed alongside Oracle